# SQL Server - error running 'sp_addsubscription' when not sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, replication, security

- Windows 2008 R2
- MSSQLSERVER 2012 (SP1) Standard

When running *sp_addsubscription* under account within db_owner role of both user and distribution databases, I get the following error:

**Msg 14260, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSadd_subscriber_info, Line 44
You do not have sufficient permission to run this command. Contact your system administrator.
Msg 14042, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addsubscriber, Line 342
Could not create Subscriber.**

...despite books online (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181702.aspx) stating that “…db_owner fixed database role can execute sp_addsubscription”.

*sp_addsubscription* appears to kick off another sys procedure called *sp_MSadd_subscriber_info* which requires sysadmin:

**-- Security Check
    IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') != 1
    BEGIN
        -- "You do not have sufficient permission to run this command."
        RAISERROR(14260, 16, -1)
        RETURN 1
    END**

Therefore, sp_addsubscription cannot be run without sysadmin seemingly.

I've also recreated this on a Windows 2012 R2 machine running MSSQLSERVER 2012 (standard).

However, on a Windows 2012 R2 machine running MSSQLSERVER 2014, the issue does  **NOT** present itself.

Cannot find any information online on this. Is this a bug with earlier versions of windows / SQL does anyone know? Alternatively, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by ensuring *distributor_admin* (or login it is replaced by) is in **sysadmin** server role